# java.lang.OutOfMemory Error When Trying to Implement SSL/TLS in Kafka on Windows

Tags: windows, ssl, apache-kafka

I am trying to implement encryption and authentication using SSL/TLS in Kafka on Windows. I created the TLS keys and Certificates according to this [link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/security_tutorial.html#creating-ssl-keys-and-certificates) and set the following properties in server.properties:

```
listeners=SSL://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=SSL://<host-name>:9092 *
ssl.keystore.location=C:/DataGrid/Kafka/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=C:/DataGrid/Kafka/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.client.auth=required
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
super.users=User:<host-name>
security.protocol=SSL
```

But when trying to create a topic using the following command in cmd:

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server <host-name>:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

I get this error:

```
C:\DataGrid\Kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server vmnala:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
[2020-06-17 11:52:49,629] ERROR Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1': (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:112)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:424)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:385)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:651)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:572)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:539)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1152)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Looking at server.log I see the following error:

```
[2020-06-17 11:52:49,567] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1] Failed authentication with /10.2.9.200 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

Besides, when trying to create a consumer in python I get:

```
>>> from kafka import KafkaConsumer
>>> c = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='vmnala:9092', security_protocol = "SSL")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\group.py", line 324, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 826, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
>>>
```

Any ideas what can be the cause of it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you configured your brokers to use `SSL` but you are not configuring your clients to do so. By default, clients use `PLAINTEXT`.

For `kafka-topics`, you need to give it a file via `--command-config` that contains the required properties. Something like:

```
ssl.truststore.location=<PATH>
ssl.truststore.password=<PASSWORD>
security.protocol=SSL
```

For the Python client, you need to specify the corresponding configs in the constructor. See https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer for the list of configurations

Comment: Thanks so much Mickael! Following your tips I ran the following code: >>> c = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='vmnala:9092', security_protocol="SSL", ssl_cafile="C:\DataGrid\Kafka\ca-cert", ssl_certfile="C:\DataGrid\Kafka\cert-signed", ssl_keyfile="C:\DataGrid\Kafka\ca-key", ssl_password="test1234"). and I got: ssl.SSLError: [X509: KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH] key values mismatch (_ssl.c:2600). But comparing the ca-key and ca-cert in openSSL gave me the same result. Can you help me a bit further?
Thanks again! :)

Comment: Dolev - Usually broker endpoint for plaintext will be configured as 9092 and for TLS/SSL will be configured as 9094 or something like tat. In the above configs, I can see you are still pointing to 9092 plaintext endpoint for bootstrap.servers.

Comment: @SurendraS Thanks for your advice! I tried it but unfortunately it didn't help. I assume the port number is more of a convention here.

Comment: @MickaelMaison no, it doesn't, I'm running "kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server vmnala:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test --command-config "C:\DataGrid\Kafka\config\client-ssl.properties"" and I get: "[AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (vmnala/10.2.9.200:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)"

Comment: I think i've found the problem, it's in the inter-broker authentication